# JFrog docker registry is not pulling images in Kubernetes

Tags: docker, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, jfrog-cli

I am using JFrog as docker registry.

If I try to manually pull an image it works, but when I try the same by including in helm chart and helm install command it is throwing an error:

```
Error: ImagePullBackOff  
pulling image registry_name/jfrogk8s:1.0 
Failed to pull image registry_name/jfrogk8s:1.0: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Error response from daemon: Get https://dip-docker-dip.bintray.io/v2/jfrogk8s/manifests/1.0: unauthorized: Unauthorized"
```

I have included docker registry in "/etc/docker/daemon.json"

Comment: Is it a private docker registry? If so, have you followed this: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/pull-image-private-registry/#registry-secret-existing-credentials ?
Additionally, I think to use a remote registry, the image has to be tagged with registry endpoint information, for example: `example.com/registry/image:latest`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It clearly says - `unauthorized: Unauthorized`

The docker registry is not invoked while pulling an internal image even though you did put `docker registry in "/etc/docker/daemon.json"` in the kubernetes environment. Hence, you need to create a `Docker Registry Secret` and later use it in helm installation to tell kubernetes to pull an internal image using this secret :

```
kubectl create secret docker-registry regcred --docker-server=<your-registry-server> --docker-username=<your-name> --docker-password=<your-pword> --docker-email=<your-email>
```

> where:
>
> - `<your-registry-server>` is your Private Docker Registry FQDN.
>     (https://index.docker.io/v1/ for DockerHub)
> - `<your-name>` : is your Docker username.
> - `<your-pword>`: is your Docker password.
> - `<your-email>`: is your Docker email.

To validate if the docker registry secret `regcred` is created do

```
kubectl get secret regcred --output=yaml
```

Then in your helm charts `value.yaml` add following line

```
imagePullSecret: regcred
```

If you need to do it the Kuberentes way your `deploy.yaml` will look like this:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: private-reg
spec:
  containers:
  - name: private-reg-container
    image: <your-private-image>
  imagePullSecrets:
  - name: regcred
```

Comment: Still, I am getting the same error. I tried a solution provided by you.

Comment: Could you update your question with deployment config and `regcred` command. Ommit the URL and password, that's obvious.

Comment: One more thing, your kube cluster, can it access JFrog repo. I'm assuming the JFrog is internal (behind firewall) so is that accessible from the kube network?